# How to see the output of a service in a docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, docker-swarm

With Docker Compose, when we run `docker-compose up` we see the output of all services being presented on the console, even with different colors to make it easier to distinguish them. Even if we have multiple instances of a service, the output of all of them appears there.

Now, today I've tried deploying a stack to a swarm with Docker Compose v3 for the first time.

After I do

```
docker deploy stack --compose-file=docker-compose.yml the_stack
```

I can see the services running by using

```
docker service ls
```

However, I'd like to see the output of the services as in Docker Compose.

For instance, if I have a service `background_worker` with 3 replicas running in one node, I'd like to be able to see in that node the output of these replicas as I do with Docker Compose.

How can I see the output of a replicated service deployed in a Docker Stack with Docker Swarm?

**Edit**: As answered, I need to enable experimental options on your docker daemon, however, I'm running this inside a docker-machine created with the hyperv driver, since it is not yet possible to run a multi-node swarm with Docker for Windows. How can I enable this inside the docker machine?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two options for 1.13:

1. connect to each node and run a `docker logs` on the individual containers.
2. enable experimental options on your docker daemon which will let you use [`docker service logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_logs/)

Comment: Thanks @BMitch. I'm running the node inside a docker-machine because it is a Windows host. How can I enable the experimental options? I tried enabling it in Docker for Windows, but I believe this doesn't affect the daemon running on the docker-machine.

Comment: docker-machine is getting out of my specialty. You may be able to ssh into the vm and find/change the startup script. From the docker-machine create syntax, there doesn't appear to be any way to flip the experimental flag: https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/.

Comment: I think I'll do as you suggest, ssh into the VM and change the /etc/docker/daemon.json file as explained in the page https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/experimental

Comment: The docs seem to suggest you can pass `--engine-opt` to `docker-machine create` then a daemon flag and this will be set on the daemon inside the `docker-machine` instance. So maybe `--engine-opt experimental` will work? Not tested though. See https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/#/specifying-configuration-options-for-the-created-docker-engine.